# for_each implementation with tolower

Tags: c++, foreach, tolower

I'm having trouble implementing the use of `for_each`, I can get the job done with a for loop, but for the sake of understanding, I could use some help with an explanation...I have the following function thus far...

```
void clean_entry(const string& orig, string& cleaned) {
        size_t start = 0;
        size_t end = 0; 

        while(!isalnum(orig[start]) && start < orig.length())
                start++;
        end = start;
        while(isalnum(orig[end]) && end < orig.length())
                end++;

        cleaned = orig.substr(start,(end-start));
        // I want to replace the following lines with a for_each loop
        string::iterator iter;
        for(iter = cleaned.begin(); iter != cleaned.end(); iter++)
                *iter = tolower(*iter);
}
```

In my attempts to implement a for_each loop for the last three lines of code in the above function, I tried the following which gave me a compile error...

```
struct {
     void operator()(string::iterator strIter) {
          *strIter = tolower(*strIter);
     }
  } lower;
  for_each(cleaned.begin(),cleaned.end(),lower);
```

Comment: Do you have C++11 (i.e., lambdas) available to you?

Answer (score 1):

`std::for_each` applies a functor to **each element in the given range.** It passes the actual elements to your functor (`*it`), not the iterator itself.

In your case, `void operator()(string::iterator strIter)` should be changed to `void operator()(string::value_type& character)`

Answer (score 1):

I really like dauphic's answer -- that should just work.

If you do have a C++11-compliant(-ish;) compiler, you can get rid of the `struct`, and simply replace the `for` loop with this:

```cpp
std::for_each(
    cleaned.begin(), 
    cleaned.end(), 
    [](char &c) { c = tolower(c); });
```

PS Since you asked for an explanation: the last parameter to `for_each()` is a lambda expression. The lambda function will be called once for every character in the string. To break it down even further:

- `[]`: the empty set here means that none of `clean_entry()`'s variables will be accessible inside of the lambda (if you wanted to reference `cleaned` inside the lambda function, you would use `[&cleaned]` instead).
- `(char &c)` (or `(string::value_type& c)`): defines how the iteration parameter (the individual characters of the string) will be passed to the lambda function (by reference, since we need to modify it).
- `{c = tolower(c);}`: the body of the lambda function, self-explanatory.

PPS For the sake of completeness: I am assuming that this is just to play with for_each, and not for actual production code, since `tolower()`, as used here, doesn't deal with locales, and other approaches can be more concise / clear, such as

```
  for (char &c : cleaned) {
        c = tolower(c);
  }
```

or

```
std::transform(cleaned.begin(), cleaned.end(), cleaned.begin(), tolower);
```

.